# Manual rendering failed

Tags: html, django

Manually rendering the page, but it didn't work as I thought

```
#html
<input  class="" for="{{art_form.title}}" required>

#form.py
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'subject']

#google Elements;Actual output code
<input  class="" for="<input type="text" name="title" value="这是一篇测试文章111" maxlength="255" required id="id_title">" required>
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you include a tag in a tag?

Comment: What rendering are you expecting ?

Comment: I need to render the labels manually, and don't want to use 'form' form rendering

Comment: Because manual rendering is more flexible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,render the form through 'form. Py' to achieve the effect.
Or add class and ID to let the front end render.

```
#form.py
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'subject']
        error_messages = {
            'title': {
                'required': _('请输入标题'),
                'max_length': _('标题最多50个字'),
                'min_length': _('内容太少，请重新填写'),
            },
            'body': {
                'required': _('请输入内容'),
                'min_length': _('内容太少，请重新填写'),
            }
        }
        widgets = {
            #字段样式
            'title': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': '请输入标题(最多50个字)'})
        }
```